JiraWatcher - A script that helps track the progress of testing versions
There are several versions that can include subversions.
The description field contains a Git log of changes, for example:
8155a946 feat: TEST-123. any description
0b1b9c40 feat: TEST-33 - some other description

Where TEST is the name of the project, and the numbers are the task numbers.
The script logs in to Jira, goes through the versions and subversions, collects the numbers of tasks included in the version and also tasks linked to these versions, these are problems created during testing.
After that, it generates a table, a kind of report. How many tasks in total were included in the version, how many of them are not yet closed (not tested). What bugs were created.
The code works, but since I'm a newbie, I'm interested in getting feedback and hearing recommendations.
import re
import os
import requests
from enum import StrEnum
from pathlib import Path
from atlassian import Jira
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from prettytable import PrettyTable

class Versions(StrEnum):
    v_1_1 = 'QA-401'
    v_1_2 = 'QA-404'

load_dotenv()

jira = Jira(
    url=os.getenv('JIRA_URL'),
    username=os.getenv('JIRA_USERNAME'),
    password=os.getenv('JIRA_PASSWORD')
)

jira_table = PrettyTable()
jira_table.field_names = [
    'key',
    'status',
    'summary',
    'issuetype',
    'priority',
    'assignee',
    'creator'
]

jira_table.align = 'l'
jira_table.sortby = 'status'

status_ignore: list[str] = [
    'Approved',
    'Closed',
    'Rejected',
    'Declined'
]

reports_dir: str = 'report'
Path(reports_dir).mkdir(exist_ok=True)


def report_table(name, source):
    for key_issue in source:
        try:
            ticket = jira.issue(key_issue)

            if ticket['fields']['status']['name'] not in status_ignore:
                jira.issue_add_watcher(
                    ticket['key'],
                    os.getenv('JIRA_USERNAME')
                )
                jira_table.add_row(
                    [
                        ticket['key'],
                        ticket['fields']['status']['name'],
                        ticket['fields']['summary'][:100] + '...' if len(ticket['fields']['summary']) > 100 else ticket['fields']['summary'],
                        ticket['fields']['issuetype']['name'],
                        ticket['fields']['priority']['name'],
                        ticket['fields']['assignee']['displayName'],
                        ticket['fields']['creator']['displayName']
                    ]
                )
        # requests.exceptions.HTTPError: Issue Does Not Exist
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
            pass

    jira_table.title = f'{name} (Total: {len(source)}, Not Closed: {jira_table.__getattr__("rowcount")})'

    report.write(jira_table.get_string())
    report.write('\n')

    jira_table.clear_rows()


def issues_fields(key):
    if key['fields']['description'] is not None:
        issues_gitlog.update(
            re.findall(
                # https://ihateregex.io/expr/jira-ticket
                pattern=r'[A-Z]{2,}-\d+',
                string=key['fields']['description']
            )
        )

    for issue_link in key['fields']['issuelinks']:
        try:
            issues_qa.add(issue_link['outwardIssue']['key'])
        except KeyError:
            issues_qa.add(issue_link['inwardIssue']['key'])


for version in Versions:
    issues_gitlog = set()
    issues_qa = set()
    version = jira.issue(version)

    issues_fields(key=version)

    for subtask in version['fields']['subtasks']:
        subtask = jira.issue(subtask['key'])

        issues_fields(key=subtask)

    with open(f'{reports_dir}/{version["fields"]["summary"]}.txt', 'w') as report:
        report_table(name='Git Log', source=issues_gitlog)
        report_table(name='Issue Links', source=issues_qa)


module-level actions
load_dotenv()

jira = Jira(
    url=os.getenv('JIRA_URL'),
    username=os.getenv('JIRA_USERNAME'),
    password=os.getenv('JIRA_PASSWORD')
)

You're doing a little more at top level than I'm comfortable with.
I'm concerned that a missing dot file or env var could cause import of
this module to fail, and there's no reason for that.
For example pytest might be scanning for "test_" functions to call.
Better to hide such actions within def main(): or whatever,
and then execute them when someone actually wants the behavior they offer.
Similarly with that for loop down at the end.
Use the customary if __name__ == "__main__": guard
so they won't run at import time.
helpful identifiers
Certainly jira_table is descriptive.
But we use it a bunch of times, and the table type is very clear.
Probably just table would suffice.
modern type annotation
status_ignore: list[str] = [ ...

Given that we're assigning a bunch of quoted str literals,
it feels weird to explicitly call out that we have a list[str].
It's definitely correct, but it's also redundant in the sense
that pyright or mypy will immediately infer that.
So it just seems more like noise than something helpful.
Similarly for
reports_dir: str = 'report'.
Prefer to run mypy --strict, so instead of an unhelpful
signature like def report_table(name, source):
we would see the input and output types.
explicit failure message
Down in report_table() I don't understand this expression:
                    os.getenv('JIRA_USERNAME')

Better to write os.environ['JIRA_USERNAME'],
to explicitly say that this is a mandatory env var, it must be present.
And if it isn't, we get an informative KeyError diagnostic.
The OP code as written will pass in None and then
later produce a confusing diagnostic that the network transaction
failed for some non-obvious reason.
add helper
This expression is mostly fine as-is.
                        ticket['fields']['summary'][:100] + '...' if len(ticket['fields']['summary']) > 100 else ticket['fields']['summary'],

But it would be more convenient to def summarize(),
which optionally introduces the '...' ellipsis as needed.
If nothing else it would let you shrink the line width a bit.
In a similar vein, you might possibly define a local temp var
fields = ticket['fields'], to let you briefly refer to
half a dozen nested items.
The try ... pass is a little surprising.
If caller passes in a key_issue I feel it is reasonable to expect
there's a good chance Jira will acknowledge the issue exists.
Instead of pass consider sending a
logger
a DEBUG message that mentions key_issue,
or appending a line to some log file.
change in meaning
for version in Versions:
    ...
    version = jira.issue(version)

    issues_fields(key=version)

Python doesn't get upset by it, but for the sake of your human readers
it's usually a bad idea to reassign loop variable such as version.
The assignment is changing the meaning, and probably the type,
of that variable. Choose a new name for a new concept.
Also, issues_fields(key=jira.issue(version)) would suffice,
letting that intermediate expression be anonymous with no new name.
getattr
I don't know the Jira API and have not consulted their docs,
but this expression seems weird:
jira_table.__getattr__("rowcount").
Shouldn't that be jira_table["rowcount"]?
Maybe it's just an idiosyncrasy of that library.
It is mind boggling to me that the obvious query of len(jira_table)
would fail with
TypeError: object of type 'PrettyTable' has no len()
due to lack of a __len__ method.
globals
Yikes! Most of the OP code is really pretty good, but this
signature is just terrible:
def issues_fields(key):
    ...
        issues_gitlog.update( ...
            ...
            issues_qa.add( ...

We have no """docstring""", not even a comment, warning us
that we evaluate for side effects upon those two issues_FOO globals.
Minimally you need to warn future maintenance engineers about that.
But much better, place both of them in the signature so it is obvious.
Or consider turning functions into class methods so we can
mutate self.issues_gitlog and self.issues_qa.
As a separate item, maybe we'd like just a single issues object?
Which has distinct gitlog and qa issue containers?

I'll split the answer into several comments, I'll start with the easiest one for me. __getattr__ is related to the PrettyTable library, it is used to determine the actual number of rows in the table.

I couldn't find this __getattr__ method in the documentation right now, I don't remember where I read it. It was several years ago. It seems that the source code is the only place where it is mentioned https://github.com/prettytable/prettytable/blob/main/src/prettytable/prettytable.py. I also found that there is an alternative in the form of len(table.rows). Thanks for pushing me to this research.

os.environ['TEST'] thanks for the recommendation, I'll have to study this topic in more detail. Never thought that there are several options for reading the environment change.

Overview
You did a good job with:

Leveraging others code with the imports
Using meaningful names for classes, functions and variables.

Layout
Move the functions to the top after the import lines.
Having them in the middle of the code interrupts the natural flow of the
code (from a human readability standpoint).
Documentation
You should add a docstring at the top of the code to:

Summarize its purpose
Emphasize it relies on an external .env file with environment variables
Describe the output files it generates

The PEP 8 style guide recommends
using docstrings for the functions as well.
Simpler
Consider combining these 2 lines :
version = jira.issue(version)

issues_fields(key=version)

as:
issues_fields(key=jira.issue(version))

The same goes for the 2 lines:
    subtask = jira.issue(subtask['key'])

    issues_fields(key=subtask)

Tools
Since you are new to Python, perhaps these code development
tools
could be of use.

Thanks for your time, I need to process all this. So I'll split the answer into several comments. I accepted your recommendation for issues_fields(key=jira.issue(subtask['key'])), but with issues_fields(key=jira.issue(version)) - it doesn't work. It leads to the error for subtask in version['fields']['subtasks']: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'. Since we rely on the version variable here

In the order of the code, we always thought that after imports comes the definition of variables, after that comes the definition of functions and their use. But apparently I was wrong about this.

@ykoavlil: You're welcome.  I was unable to run the code myself to check if combining the lines would work (I don't have access to a Jira database).  It was just a suggestion.
